# Multiple routes in ConnectedRouter in React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have requirement where I want to render different component on different Routes
so

- http://localhost/page1 should Render Page1
- http://localhost/page2 should Render Page2
- http://localhost/page3 should Render Page3
- http://localhost/ should Render Animal

Am using following configuration for this? Is this right or do community recommend something else to be used for this?

```
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';

<ConnectedRouter history={app.history}>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        <Route exact path="/page3" component={Page3} />
        <Route exact path="/:animal?" component={Animal} />
    </div>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exact path, you might wanna use Index route as in future you might need to add children. So, it's a good practice to keep App decoupled from your other paths and let the route config decide what to render as the children.(In case you have that in future)

Remember, we want to build small apps inside small apps, not big ones!

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={some_component}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/xyz" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={xyz}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/abc" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component= {abc}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/*" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume the OP is using v4 from the way he has written up his code, so this thing wont help

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes I am using v4 and mentioned in question subject.